# Download Video in Users Device Python Django

Tags: python, django, youtube-dl

I'm making a **Django app** where users can paste link and download videos but there's a problem. I've tried to run it on my local server and then on WAN but both times results are same. Video is downloaded in my directory rather than users. I'm using **youtube-dl** for this. I'll be really thankful if someone help me out with this. I'll add the **views.py** file so you get a better understanding. Thanks!

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from download.models import urlinput
from download.forms import Input
import youtube_dl
import subprocess
import os
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
form=Input()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=Input(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            link=form['url'].value()
            #downloadaudio(link)
            #video1080(link)
            #homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
            #dirs=homedir +'/Downloads'
            video720(link)
            #download4k(link)
            form.save(commit=True)
            return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})
       else:
           print("Invalid Input")
return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})
def downloadaudio(link):
options={'format':'bestaudio/best','extractaudio':True,'audioformat':'mp3'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
def video1080(link):
options={'format':'bestvideo+bestaudio/best'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
def video720(link):
options={'format':'best'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
def download4k(link):
subprocess.call("youtube-dl -f 299+140 {}".format(link))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
```

To this

```
homedir = os.path.expanduser("~user")
```

So that it refers to the user's dir.

You can read on `os.path.expanduser` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) from the docs.

Comment: I've tried this but it's not working, It is still downloading in my directory. I port forwarded it and try to use it in my mobile but same results just my system directory is changed.